# Considering Loading in analysis and design

Tags: power, operational-amplifier, amplifier, analog

What are the conditions under which loading can or cannot be ignored? I would like to be able to design a circuit in segments and then connect these segments together to create a circuit that performs all the operations of the individual circuits. 
To my understanding, loading refers to the condition when the first stages output voltage is reduced when it is driving the second stage, as compared with the output voltage if the second stage were not present. How can this be accounted for in ones analysis or design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case, it's an iterative process, where you design all of the stages in isolation first, then adjust the design of each stage to account for the actual values found in the previouis pass. Usually, this will converge quickly.

However, if you can design your stages up front so that the input impedance is an order of magnitude or two (i.e., 10× to 100×) greater than the output impedance of the previous stage, then no iteration should be required.

Alternatively, you can plan ahead what the interface impedances are going to be and design each stage for that specific impedance on each end. Usually, you have enough degrees of freedom to make this a straightforward task.

Comment: Just to clarify, what is the number of degrees of freedom? Is it the number of independent voltage sources or current sources of the sub-circuits

Comment: The different variables you are able to adjust in your design. Like the R L and C values in a filter circuit.

Comment: By designing the input impedance of the next stage to be an order of magnitude greater than the output impedance of the current stage, is this simply minimizing the amount of mismatch? That is, will this introduce noise into the circuit from the finite mismatch?

Comment: No, impedance mismatches do not introduce noise.